# Create a dynamic nested array object from object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
"params": {
    "name": "Alexa",
    "lastName": "Simpson",
    "city": "London"
  }
```

Here's the request that I need to implement: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate

I want to create an array of objects and pass the key of my object to the value of "text". for example "name" goes to {{text1}} and "Alexa" to "replaceText1" dynamically.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "replaceAllText": {
        "containsText": {
          "text": "{{text1}}",
          "matchCase": "true"
        },
        "replaceText": "replaceText1"
      }
    },
    {
      "replaceAllText": {
        "containsText": {
          "text": "{{value2}}",
          "matchCase": "true"
        },
        "replaceText": "replaceText2"
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of `obj.param` to create a request object for each key/value pair, then place that as the value in an object with a key of `requests`:

```js
const obj = {
  "params": {
    "name": "Alexa",
    "lastName": "Simpson",
    "city": "London"
  }
}

const req = {
  "requests": Object.entries(obj.params).map(([text, value]) =>
    ({
      "replaceAllText": {
        "containsText": {
          "text": text,
          "matchCase": "true"
        },
        "replaceText": value
      }
    }))
}

console.log(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This uses [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the `key`, `value` pair and they are used as a resulting objects. You can parse the `params` object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
params = {
"name": "Alexa",
"lastName": "Simpson",
"city": "London"
}

requests = []

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(params)) {
  requests.push({
"replaceAllText": {
  "containsText": {
    "text": k,
    "matchCase": "true"
  }
},
"replaceText": v
  })
}

console.log(`{requests: ${JSON.stringify(requests)}`)
```

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert to the resulting string.